# How to put calendar on uiviewcontroller?

Tags: ios

I wanna put calendar on uiviewcontroller. 
calendar's dates are must be button. When click button, display another page.

But i don't have idea, can you give any idea?

ps: insert example picture....

[image]

Comment: We won't do your homework. Show us exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: Sorry for your angry.. but i'm not student, just newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your custom calendar.

You can search on this for [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar) and use which one is appropriate for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use **TapKu Library** it may be best for you.

https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary

**OR**

Use **`klazuka_Calendar`**

https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

[And Also This is best site for all custom Calendar.](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar)